# javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

Getting `javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'` when running a web app. To me the `@RequestMapping`, tiles configuration and mapping looks good but still getting an error.

Here is the WebAppInitializr.java

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootConfig.class, MessageSourceConfig.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(WebMvcConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

And the WebAppConfig

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.examples" })
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String TILES_VIEW_RESOLVER_DEFINITION = "/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles_configuration.xml";

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        tilesViewResolver.setOrder(2);
        return tilesViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { TILES_VIEW_RESOLVER_DEFINITION });
        tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }

}
```

The request mapping i have in the controller is:
`@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

And the tiles definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="defaultTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/views/templates/baseLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="meta" value="/WEB-INF/views/templates/meta.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="navbar" value="/WEB-INF/views/templates/navbar.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/templates/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="home" extends="defaultTemplate">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Home" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Any help resolving this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Thunder, Could you please show your baseLayout.jsp page? I also face this error today and able to resolved it. You need to specify your meta, navbar, body and footer in the baseLayout.jsp in the following ways, <tiles:insertAttribute name="ATTRIBUTE_NAME" />. If you want to make some tile optional then you need to write <tiles:insertAttribute name="ATTRIBUTE_NAME" ignore="true"/>

Comment: `<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/includes/taglibs.jsp" %>

<html>
<head>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="meta"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="navbar"/>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
</body>
</html>` This is how my baseLayout.jsp looks like.

Comment: You need to add this code inside your <title> element like following, **<title><tiles:getAsString name="title"/></title>**

Answer (score 0):

In your tile definition file you put the `title` attribute but in the your baseLayout.jsp file you didn't placed it. You need to add the following line of code inside your `<title>` element of the **baseLayout.jsp** file

```
<title><tiles:getAsString name="title"/></title>
```